# Drilldown in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to create a drilldown report in SSRS. My requirement is that I have various products that may be a 'child' of a one or more 'parent' product.

My dataset returns products with various stock information. They all contain a 'product level' column, that is 'child' or 'parent'. Each 'child' also contains 'parent 1', 'parent 2' and 'parent 3' columns (3 is the max).

I would like to show all the 'child' products, and then drilldown to show the one or more 'parent' products that are associated to that child

Something like:

```
product level | code | desc | qty
____________________________________
child         | 123  | screw| 5  

drilldown

product level | code | desc | qty
____________________________________
child         | 123  | screw| 5  
parent 1      | abc  | seat | 0
parent 2      | xyz  | table| 0
```

Can I do this with the data as described?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your data structure so we can see how the products are related in the database.